# ajax call to refresh partial view on detail page not working after edit action from modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial in a `Detail` view. I use a modal with the edit action to update the child relationship of the record in the `Detail` view. When I hit `Save` on the edit modal, the record updates, and I want the partial that holds the child relationship data to refresh, instead of the the whole page refreshing.

So far, I've been able to get the edit modal to work with ajax. But my script for refreshing the partial isn't working. I put a breakpoint in the controller action called by the ajax script but when clicking the `Save` button on the modal edit form the breakpoint never fires. I don't know why the controller action isn't being called by the ajax script.

The `Detail` view is a bootstrap tabbed view. The tab I am working on is the `Relationships` tab. When I use the `Edit` modal to update a relationship, I want the `Relationship` tab to refresh, not the whole page.

I should note that the `Edit` modal is a view component based on the `Relationship` model, and the `Detail` view is based on the `Contact` model. This part works. I put the line `return NoContent();` at the end of the `Relationship` controller `POST;Edit` action. I used the click event of the `Save` button to handle closing the `Edit` modal and refreshing the partial in the `Detail` view.

script

```
function refreshRelationships() {
    closeEdit(); // closes the Edit Modal
    req = $.ajax({
        url: "/Contacts/RefreshRelationshipsTab/",
        method: "GET",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#nav-relationship").html("");
            $("#nav-relationship").html(response);
        }
    });
};
```

Partial View `_RelationshipsTab`

```
@if (@Model.RelationshipsAsParent.Count > 0)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.RelationshipsAsParent.Count; j++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.RelationshipsAsParent[j].Child.FullName</td>
                    <td>@Model.RelationshipsAsParent[j].RelationshipType.Type</td>
                    <td>
                        <a onclick="RelationshipsEdit(@Model.RelationshipsAsParent[j].Id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                            Edit
                        </a> |
                        <a asp-controller="Relationships" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.RelationshipsAsParent[j].Id">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
else
{
    <h3>No Relationships</h3>
}
```

Contacts Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshRelationshipsTab()
{
    return PartialView("_RelationshipsTab");
}
```

Button in Edit Modal form

```
<button onclick="refreshRelationships()" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Partial View div in Details view

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-relationship" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-relationship-tab">
    <partial name="_RelationshipsTab"/>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why is the button of type="submit"? It does not submit anything and if it is in a form, you want to add the call to the submit of the form with a preventDefault, since the form will submit with unexpected results

Comment: Also no need to do  `$("#nav-relationship").html("");` before a `$("#nav-relationship").html(response);`

Comment: When I prevent the default the Edit never happens and the relationship is not updated in the database.

Comment: So `url: "/Contacts/RefreshRelationshipsTab/",` does not update

Comment: No. That url calls an action that returns the partial view, and it doesn't refresh that partial view on the `Details` page. I updated the OP with the model edit functionality if that helps.